# Humming and Transmission issues

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, sound, telephone, distortion

First of all, I am going through designing all of this because I did not find a ready made circuitry for my purpose which is mentioned later. If you know a circuitry that is well tested and does what I want, by all means share it.

So I have this circuit:

[image: Schematic]

[Bigger picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNqLo.jpg)

It is a computer-soundcard <-> telephone interface with Headphones to monitor.

Power supply is to be a symmetric 9V Power supply. PC Speaker(top-left) is the headphone output jack. The hum is in the headphones(bottom-right).

Two problems:

1. When connection to PC speaker is plugged in and Telephone connection(bottom-left) is plugged in, I hear humming in the headphones. When only one is plugged in I hear it without distortion.  [Sound files showing humming](http://filedropper.com/sound_2).
2. (Solved) When playing audio, it is almost not audible on the telephone side, ie, the person I am playing it to cannot hear it.

Please share ideas on how to solve the issues.

If you criticise my circuitry, add something to act as a replacement, too. Just saying that it won't work because of this and that is not as helpful as saying: "It won't work because of X, which is why I recommend doing Y". I try to update this question with the current circuit so you don't have to scroll through all replies to get the current status.

PS: Circuitry for telephone connection taken from [a recording interface](http://hackipedia.org/Protocols/Telephone,%20POTS/html/teleinterface.html) from Tekniikan Maailma magazine. I chose it to be able to use the circuit in parallel with my current phone.

Comment: Please include power supply details in your schematic. What exactly is GND? Are the op-amps on a dual voltage supply?

Comment: "PC Speaker" actually refers to the headphone or line output jack of your computer, is that correct?

Comment: Is the hum in the phone, or in the PC?

Comment: I updated it and answered all your questions there.

Comment: The random noise is so bad, I am not sure if any of this design can be salvaged. The dial tone, fundamental hum was less than the random broadband noise. Common mode rejection and 600 ohm impedance matching are key elements of a good telephony interface design which this one lacks.  A good design should have noise at -60dBmv and start with a proper hybrid Xfmr. Why not modify/interface to a working phone?

Comment: @Richman I want you to draw a circuit that shows how to modify my current circuit to work properly. I do not want to read a new term in every other reply you write that makes it even more challenging to understand what you are talking about. If you know your stuff, Richman, you can draw it. Oh and don't draw "black boxes" like "here goes the amplifier". Thank you.

Comment: @Richman Interfacing to my phone's handset does not solve the humming when plugged in to the computer's speaker alone.

Comment: @Kaz We are working on small details here that do not work together. I want you to draw, yes draw not just describe, a circuit that helps me achieve the goals I described. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does connecting PC ground cause the noise with no speaker connection?

Comment: The 600ohm line impedance is a North American Standard. It is different elsewhere in the world and in Germany they use a reactive network impedance for load matching. YOu need to start with these basics, then choose an appropriate Hybrid transformer and loading circuit to isolate Rx Tx signals and improve CM rejection. Tweaking your mis-matched design wont help much you understand why it is noisy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Regarding your power supply. You have created a dual supply with two batteries. Batteries have internal resistance and so should be bypassed by capacitors. Any resistance in your return circuit can create ground loops. When a dual supply is created using batteries, there is a risk that it will go lopsided if one battery loses voltage faster than the other one.
2. You have a number of sloppy choices of part values in your circuit. For example at the bottom, you have a virtual ground mixer whose input impedance is is only 100 ohms. First of all, that is a low input impedance to ask the other op-amp to drive. Secondly, it loads down the 10K pot that you have in front of it. Weird things will happen.  When the pot is turned all the way up, the impedance is basically just the 150 ohms. The pot's impedance to ground doesn't matter because it is much larger. When you turn it halfway, the impedance goes up because now you have a 5K branch of the pot in series with the input impedance. If you want a potentiometer to be linear, it should have an impedance which is at least 10X lower than the input facing the wiper.  If you have approximately equal input (say 10K linear pot, 10K resistance) then it's nonlinear in a useful way because it approximates audio taper.
3. The gain on your upper op-amp, from the PC speaker, is less than unity, because you have a 1.5K feedback resistor and a 2.2K input resistor.  That low gain, combined with the terrible loading presented by the next stage (at least when the volume pot is turned all the way up) is probably why you have inadequate signal going back across the transformer.
4. The 450uF coupler between the transformer and your op-amp-ology is quite overblown
   . If you achieve a decent input impedance in the mixer, you can use a much smaller cap. Since you have a dual supply, you should not need it at all. The only thing it does is protect the transformer winding from DC flowing across it, if your twp batteries become unbalanced (so that the output of the upper op-amp develops a serious DC offset at quiescence). Similarly, the coupler to the headphones should also not be needed except for the threat of unbalanced batteries. If the headphones are 600 ohms, what would be a good coupler value, if we want low end down to 20 Hz? (And do we?) For flat down to 20Hz into 600 ohms, the cap would have to be 130 uF. Yours is spec'd for elephant ears: flat down to 5 Hz.   You can bridge op-amps to create an amplifier that doesn't require DC coupling to a speaker. Be sure to use parts that can drive 600 ohm loads well, like NE5532 or LM4562. The noteworthy NJM4556 can drive 150 ohm loads.
5. Regarding the hum; it is obvious from the sound files that the hum occurs when the phone is plugged in, whether or not the PC speaker is plugged in. It is 50 Hz hum. (I didn't notice you're European until examining this file! When I play it side by side with a 50 Hz tone generated in Audacity, the beat frequency between the two is very low: the frequencies coincide very closely.) There is a noticeable difference in the level of the hum when the PC audio is jacked in, suggestive of a ground loop between the PC and the phone system. (That ground loop would be external: in your device, you do not have a ground between the two but rather an isolating transformer.) But a more plausible hypothesis is this. Signal from the transformer secondary spills into the top op-amp circuit. You have two different connections from the transformer to that circuit. The PC audio output almost certainly has a low impedance to ground, so when you plug in, imagine that you're connecting jack's tips to the sleeve (if not with a conductor then at least with a capacitor for AC signals: the PC could have a coupling output capacitor that blocks DC; we don't know). This change in the circuit topology is likely the reason for the difference in the level of the hum.  About fixing it, no ideas. If I had to guess, I would say that problem (or at least *a* problem) is that the local telephone circuit from the box to your phone jack is an unbalanced, unshielded line: just two wires twisted together. That is susceptible to noise.

Comment: Yes, I experienced your first point. Half of the wave is cut and everything is distorted. Do you have a recommendation for a better power supply? It doesn't have to be mobile.

Comment: Regarding the second, which values do you recommend instead while keeping the 10 k pots?

Comment: I solved the third by replacing with a 33k feedback resistor.

Comment: re 4: The 470 uF is there to protect the headphones and to allow lower frequencies. Telephone frequencies start at 130 Hz and I think for this the capacitor is not too big. You never know what comes out of a telephone line. BTW: The upper part of the transformer is to "send", the lower to "receive". But even if the capacitors were too big/unnecessary, would they do harm/contribute to the issues I experience? The headphones are Left: 98 Ohms, Right: 103 Ohms.

Comment: With a 10K pot, we could get away with as little as Rin = Rf = 10K in the inverting mixer (unity gain situation). 20K would make the response closer to linear. Since you want some gain there, say Rin = 20K, and Rf = 100K for a gain of 5 (or rather -5).

Comment: I see, your phones have intermediate impedance. What op-amp IC are you using? Can that thing drive two 100 ohm phones, and in parallel (50 ohms?)  Whether it's related to the issue or not is hard to say. Probably not, but loading down amplifier outputs beyond their driving ability is never a good thing.

Comment: "Since you want some gain there, say Rin = 20K, and Rf = 100K for a gain of 5 (or rather -5)." Are you talking about replacing the 100 ohms and 150 ohms with 22k and the 47k with 100k(33k is short-circuited to avoid unsoldering) or are you talking about replacing the 2k2 ohms and 2k2 ohms with 22k and the now 33k with 100k? (Replaced the 20k with 22k as I only have 22k here)

Comment: "What op-amp IC are you using" Tl072CP, ie one chip for both opamps.

Comment: @DonatusOrth ^ The former. The mixer circuit lower in the diagram.

Comment: Good. I measured about 0.02 to 0.2 Volts coming from the transformer ie lower op-amp, upper connection, the one with 100 ohms being fed into and 0.77V below, thus different resistors. The upper opamp part is both 0.77V as sources. Does your 22k on both sides solution work with that?

Comment: What about the resistors for the upper virtual earth mixer circuit? Right now the upper part is finally working but seems to drain a lot of battery quickly.

Comment: The upper circuit only has a 2K input impedance after the pot, which is low for line level coupling (we usually shoot for around 10k). When the volume is turned all the way up, the impedance is that of the 2K in parallel with the 10K pot, so less than 2K. That 2K could be beefed up to something like 20K. But now you have a 33K feedback resistor, which would also have to be scaled 10 times to maintain the same gain.

Comment: The TL072 is only useful for driving loads of 2 kiloohms or higher. You break that in two places: the 50 ohm headphone load, as well as the transformer windings (the first op-amp's output is grounded through the transformer winding and a small resistor). This transformer winding could be where power is wasted. If there is any voltage difference between the output of that op-amp and GND, a current will flow. The more unbalanced the batteries, the more will flow.

Comment: The batteries are unbalanced. I will simply add another opamp as impedance converter.

Comment: I tried to include what you and Richman said into this http://i.imgur.com/HGoVH.jpg Tell me if that's what you meant. All OpAmps are TL07X, ie two TL072 containing of four TL071. If that OpAmp isn't working, recommend another one or a circuit that should be between the load and the opamp output.

Comment: Buffers won't fix anything, they just move the problem down one element. The previous thing has an easy time driving the buffer, but the buffer is the same kind of op-amp with the same limitations. What's worse, noninverting buffers run into the common-mode input range problem.  None of my favorite audio op amps are great for maximizing battery power.  Check out this puppy though: http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8591_8592_8594.pdf   250 mA sourcing ability, and only 1 mA quiescent supply current per amp. Can't get these in small quantities, though, and SMT only.

Comment: I decided to use a stabilized power unit to supply +9V GND and -9V ( http://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/159006/netzteil9vsym.gif ). Which components do you recommend now, that are widely available. As I said, the opamp doesn't need to drive the load directly if you know an alternative to put in between. OpAmps I have here: http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn95/fn957.pdf 6 times, LM 741 CN 1 time, LM358P http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358a.pdf 1 time, TL072CP 1 time. I heard the TL072CP is best for audio.

Comment: Please let's both continue in the comments field below my question for you and Richman to see.

Comment: If you're on AC power, there is no need to constrain yourself to +/- 9V! Go for 15. TL072 is not a contender for audio. A great chip for audio is the NE5532 dual op-amp which is cheap, quiet, nearly distortion-free and can drive 600 ohms. There is usually no reason to use anything else for audio.  But in your case, you have the need to drive headphones which are way less than 600 ohms.

Comment: For driving the headphones, try the NJM4556. It can go down to 150 ohm loads. Since your audio is mono, instead of putting the headphones in parallel, wire them in series!!! By paralleling the 100 ohm headphones, you create 50 ohms, which is harder to drive. If you series them, you get 200 ohms. That is more than 150, so the NJM4556 can handle it. http://semicon.njr.co.jp/eng/PDF/NJM4556A_E.pdf

Comment: I want to reuse one of my opamps. Also I do not need to go to 15V for my purpose, please keep my requirements in mind. I added a transistor circuit after that, what are your thoughts? http://i.imgur.com/FfyZz.jpg

Comment: The promised audio files are at http://www.filedropper.com/sound_2

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the hum in your phone comes from the PC power source. The high impedance coupling of the power transformer and the telephone transformer unfortunately has mutual capacitance coupling if there is no stray load to a ground plane.

If it is a PC card floating without a ground, then it will pickup radiated noise. Notice the video cable also has a CM choke for reducing interference. This is a another method for reducing harmonics of 60Hz from SMPS noise but less effective at the lower fundamental than grounding.  You can try a capacitor from battery ground to AC ground or direct connection. This is isolated for UL safety requirements with mobile units to avoid risk of shock from ground faults or insulated "wet" AC hand tools.  If you understand the risk and avoid such contact it should be safe as any grounded unit such as a PC.

Other methods can be tried such as reducing the area of the loop of high impedance signals shown in your schematic using coax and shielding to battery common (gnd).

So you can choose from grounding, shielding and common mode chokes.

Comment: Thanks. First of all humming is in the headphones, not the phone's handset. Each connection(PC Speaker, Telephone cable) on it's own does not cause humming. It is a desktop pc. Please clarify "reducing the area of the loop of high impedance signal". Also what about the second question?

Comment: Your design is not balanced impedance for common mode noise. Since the signal is fed via a 10Kohm pot, it can pick up noise from the magnetic current in the room and the area of the ground & signal loop as a antenna. Test with no audio by varying pot to full level. If noise reduces when impdance is lowered, that proves it is radiated noise. Otherwise it is conducted via the PC. Does it have any noise direct connected?

Comment: on Q2, if other person cannot hear the music, you need  -10 dBm around 0.2 Vrms from say 200 ohm source for a normal loud level. The Op Amp will likely be suitable impedance but not enough gain on Op Amp.  YOur headphone gain is huge so you may have too low a level for phone. Change Phone op Amp feedback resistor to 10X larger.

Comment: then sidetone balance issues will be next

Comment: "You can try a capacitor from battery ground to AC ground or direct connection." Doesn't that happen when connecting battery ground to PC Speaker ground? The soundcard is onboard.

Comment: "Test with no audio by varying pot to full level. If noise reduces when impdance is lowered, that proves it is radiated noise." I am not sure what you mean by "impedance is lowered". Do you mean turning the pot in the direction of increased amplification? Are you talking about the 10 k pot that feeds into the 150 or the 100 ohms resistor? Are you talking about rotating the pot while nothing is plugged in but the headphones or with either the pc speaker or the telephone line connected or with both connected?

Comment: I am going to change the 1k5 feedback resistor to 33k.

Comment: What about the 470 and 100 ohms at the bottom-left to GND? Are they useful/necessary?

Comment: What kind of hum are you hearing? Is it 60 cycle hum? Or is it "motorboating"?

Comment: I found the voltage sources to be quickly "emptied". Which resistor values would you recommend to reach a max voltage for the headphones of 2.5 Volts and for the telephone audio in to be well audible but not more, a compromise so as to speak.

Comment: Replacing the 1k5 with 33k did the trick pretty well. I appreciate that hint.

Comment: @Kaz How do I determine which kind of hum?

Comment: @DonatusOrth It can be deceiving, but low frequency oscillations reveal themselves by having a frequency other than 60 Hz, and an unstable frequency (rising or falling in pitch when you power the circuit up or down for instance, or when you change parts, turn knobs, touch parts of the circuit.

Comment: Sorry, I had wanted to add that question about hum to your question, not to this answer.

Comment: @Kaz Tomorrow when the batteries will've been recharged I will put a recorder to my headphones and send you the link.

Comment: why not use the +/-12V built inside the PC if you need power. But personally I don't think this design suits the requirements very well to mix PC audio and phone in Tx and Rx so you can monitor and presumably use PC mic to talk because the 600 ohm interface does not use the a balanced hybrid with balanced impedances for driving common mode or receiving in differential. Also your speakers may be much more sensitive to 60Hz than the phone by design. a large CM choke may be necessary when connected with hum from phone when unbalanced from PC interface

Comment: Other problems are the 4 parallel caps on the transformer. They must be non polarized and too much. The zeners are for 200Vac ring suppression but they may suppress ringing on all phones... overall this design can be tweaked to work but is sub-optimal

Comment: Richman, http://i.imgur.com/HGoVH.jpg is my current improvement. Please add EXACT values and/or replacement circuits as recommendations to your realizations. Thank you.

Comment: Please let's both continue in the comments field below my question for you and Kaz to see.

Comment: The promised audio files are at filedropper.com/sound_2